# Trying to understand the SQL hibernate generates when adding an entity to a collection in another entity

Tags: hibernate

I have two basic domain classes:

```
public class Event {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Date date;
    // getters/setters...
}

public class Person {

    private Long id;
    private int age;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet();
    // getters/setters...
}
```

This is the hibernate mapping file for the classes:

```
<class name="Event" table="EVENTS">
    <id name="id" column="EVENT_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="date" type="timestamp" column="EVENT_DATE"/>
    <property name="title"/>
</class>

<class name="Person" table="PERSON">
    <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="age"/>
    <property name="firstname"/>
    <property name="lastname"/>
    <set name="events" table="PERSON_EVENT">
        <key column="PERSON_ID"/>
        <many-to-many column="EVENT_ID" class="Event"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

If I execute the following:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Person person = (Person) session.load(Person.class, 8L);
Event event = (Event) session.load(Event.class, 4L);
person.getEvents().add(event);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The following SQL statements are executed:

```
select
    person0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON1_1_0_,
    person0_.age as age1_0_,
    person0_.firstname as firstname1_0_,
    person0_.lastname as lastname1_0_
from PERSON person0_
where person0_.PERSON_ID=?

-- Why does this do an inner join?
select
    events0_.PERSON_ID as PERSON1_1_1_,
    events0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT2_1_,
    event1_.EVENT_ID as EVENT1_0_0_,
    event1_.EVENT_DATE as EVENT2_0_0_,
    event1_.title as title0_0_
from PERSON_EVENT events0_
inner join EVENTS event1_ on events0_.EVENT_ID=event1_.EVENT_ID
where events0_.PERSON_ID=?

insert into PERSON_EVENT (PERSON_ID, EVENT_ID) values (?, ?)
```

So finally, the question:

Why does the `session.load(Event.class, 4L);` use an inner join as shown above? And not just a simple select on the Event table where the ID = 4?

Comment: That looks like the query that loads a person's events (person.getEvents()). My guess is that the query we are looking at does not come from session.load(Event.class, 4L). Are you sure there are no other SQL statements in the log?

Comment: could it be that event #4 is already in the session's cache? Hibernate maintains an identity map in the session for ensuring that each object is loaded only once...

Comment: Buritos - I think that's it, the Event is still in the hibernate cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner join is due to the many-to-many mapping of person and events. All the events of a person are loaded by `Person.getEvents()` before the event can be added.

**UPDATE**

There is no database query needed for `session.load()` because with `session.load()` Hibernate assumes the entity with the given id exists (Exception otherwise) and just generates a proxy for the given id. With `session.get()` Hibernate will go to the database (if the entity with this id is not already in the session cache or 2nd level cache) and return a persistent instance.

I think when you debug your code you will also *not* see a query for loading the person until `person.getEvents()` is called.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Right - I thought that too and that does make sense but then the question is how does the Event get loaded? There's no sql select for an Event.

Comment: I think it is because of the cache, thanks this makes sense now. Hibernate is a tricky thing when you want to get under the covers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you wonder why there is no SQL that loads your event when you do:

```
Event event = (Event) session.load(Event.class, 4L);
```

Actually the event bean returned by hibernate is not a simple pojo, but generally a class enhanced by some magic behaviours that permits to do stuff like lazy loading etc... (check dynamic proxies, CGLib / Javassist...)

---

So i'm not sure but i guess when you call:

```
Event event = (Event) session.load(Event.class, 4L);
```

Only the enhanced event bean is created, but no SQL query is fired. If you make a call on a non transient getter, the sql will probably be fired because it doesn't have the value to return for that getter yet.

Finally i guess even when you add the event to the person's event collection, the sql does not need to be fired since, to create that link, you only need the Event id.
Guess what? The enhanced event bean it certainly already knowing that id since you provided it when using the session.load -> the enhanced class is initialized with an id = 4

These are just suppositions, but try to call event.getSomething() to see if i'm right ;)